# Multiple domain extension, one server, one code, one htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have multiple domain names (FR,BE,NL,ES, ...), they are all redirected to the main webserver. The php-code is shared and is the same for all the domains & languages, I'm just identifying the active language with the param "lang=".
I would like to identify which language to use trough an .htaccess file passing a lang param, as that param is the locale, I can also identify the domain country.

Ex.

```
if mydomain.nl & page is /contact    -> /code/contact.php?lang=nl_NL
if mydomain.fr & page is /contact    -> /code/contact.php?lang=fr_FR
if mydomain.es & page is /contact    -> /code/contact.php?lang=es_ES
if mydomain.be & page is /fr/contact -> /code/contact.php?lang=fr_BE
if mydomain.be & page is /nl/contact -> /code/contact.php?lang=nl_BE 
if mydomain.be & page is /en/contact -> /code/contact.php?lang=en_BE
```

Also I would like to get rid of the "www.".

Thanks for you help,
LioH.

EDIT : 
Ok I still have a problem. I have this :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} \.be$ [NC]
RewriteRule  ^fr/a-propos$  /code/internal.php?lang=fr_BE&id=7 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule  ^fr/pourquoi$ /code/internal.php?lang=fr_BE&id=11 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule  ^fr/logout$ /scripts/logout.php?lang=fr_BE [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} \.fr$ [NC] 
RewriteRule  ^a-propos$ /code/internal.php?lang=fr_FR&id=7  [QSA,L]
RewriteRule  ^pourquoi$ /code/internal.php?lang=fr_FR&id=11 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule  ^logout$ /scripts/logout.php?lang=fr_FR [QSA,L]
```

When I try :

```
Mydomain.be/fr/logout -> It works 
Mydomain.fr/logout -> It works 
Mydomain.fr/fr/logout -> It works also but it shouldn't and will be ugly for duplicate content.
```

I've read that RewriteCond is only applicable for the very next rule, do I need to put that RewriteCond before every rules ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} \.nl$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ /code/$1.php?lang=nl_NL [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} \.fr$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ /code/$1.php?lang=fr_FR [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} \.es$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ /code/$1.php?lang=es_ES [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} \.be$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/([^/.]+)/?$ /code/$2.php?lang=$1_BE [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks anubhava for that quick reply !
I presume the "RewriteCond" is valid until a new is encountered ?

Comment: @lio It's actually valid until the next `RewriteRule`. You can combine multiple [`RewriteCond`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) if you'd like.

Comment: Yes @1ace is right `RewriteCond` is only valid until it evaluates next `RewriteRule`.

Comment: Is this correct if I do this : 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} \.nl$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^connectie$ /code/connexion.php?lang=nl_NL [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^verkopen$ /code/sale.php?lang=nl_NL [L,QSA]
...

Comment: It is difficult to understand code from comments, please edit your question and provide code there.

Comment: Yes it is true `RewriteCond is only applicable for the very next rule` so you need to add `RewriteCond` before every `RewriteRule`.